# UITableViewCell subviews not moving when editing enabled in ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview with my custom class for UITableViewCell, I have added some subviews to each of the UITableViewCell, now when I enable editing like this

```
[tableView_ setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```

a red delete button appears on left side of each cell and each cell is shifted towards right except the subviews which are added on the cell. This causes the button to appear on top of subviews. How to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UITableViewCell` have a specific view for it's content, cell.contentView, make sure all of your addSubview calls are to this view not the cell. EX:

```
// good
UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[cell.contentView addSubView:label];

// bad
[cell addSubView:label];
```